# <p> tag inside a div with gradient filter is not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, filter

I've a div with a gradient filter applied to work in IE8, inside the div I've some p tags. But the text in p tags are not rendered properly. I guess its property is inherited from filter even though it cannot be caught.  Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I've tried in different ie browsers in different machines, the machines that had ie9(on changing the document mode to ie8) are rendering fine, but the machines with only browser ie8 fails to render properly.

Comment: I assume the gradient is the background, in which case you could just create a gradient image as a jpeg in another program, such as photoshop or OpenOffice Draw and set it as the `div` background.

Comment: I just saw another option: embed the svg into the `div` with an `<object>` tag, should work with HTML 4 as well. [Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp) the link.